# Action of mixed momentum-position exponential on momentum-position state

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What is
$$\exp\left(\hat{x}_1\hat{p}_2\right)|p\rangle_1|x\rangle_2$$
where 1 and 2 correspond to different Hilbert spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $\hat{x}_1$ and $\hat{p}_2$ commute, so you can just apply them directly. This is slightly complicated by the fact that the $x$ and $p$ are 'cross-wired', but this is easily solved by putting in a relevant basis for each operator:
\begin{align}
\exp\left(\gamma \hat{x}_1\hat{p}_2\right)|p\rangle_1|x\rangle_2
& =
\exp\left(\gamma \hat{x}_1\hat{p}_2\right)
\int\!\mathrm dx'|x'\rangle_1{}_1\langle x'|
\int\!\mathrm dp'|p'\rangle_2{}_2\langle p'|
\times
|p\rangle_1|x\rangle_2
\\& =
\int\!\mathrm dx'
\!\!\int\!\mathrm dp'
\exp\left(\gamma \hat{x}_1\hat{p}_2\right)
|x'\rangle_1
|p'\rangle_2 \ 
{}_1\langle x'|p\rangle_1 \ 
{}_2\langle p'|x\rangle_2
\\& =
\frac{1}{2\pi}
\int\!\mathrm dx'
\!\!\int\!\mathrm dp'
e^{\gamma x'p'+ix'p-ixp'}
|x'\rangle_1
|p'\rangle_2
.
\end{align}
In principle, you can just stop there, because that's plenty to get you your wavefunction. The inner kernel, $e^{\gamma x'p'+ix'p-ixp'}$, is the wavefunction in the $|x\rangle_1|p\rangle_2$ basis, and if you want the wavefunction in some other combination of position and momentum representations, it's just a Fourier transform away.

Of course, that doesn't tell you all that much about the structure of the state, so you can hope for a better and cleaner representation of $\exp\left(\gamma \hat{x}_1\hat{p}_2\right)|p\rangle_1|x\rangle_2$ that will provide deeper insight. One way to do this, for example, is to pull the inner integral into a single momentum eigenstate:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\int\!\mathrm dx'
e^{\gamma x'p'+ix'p}
|x'\rangle_1
=
|p-i\gamma p'\rangle_1
$$
(This makes it very clear why I put in a constant $\gamma$ in $\exp\left(\gamma \hat{x}_1\hat{p}_2\right)$: if you want that operator to be even mildly well-behaved, you definitely want $\gamma$ to be pure imaginary.) Putting this in, then, you get
\begin{align}
\exp\left(\gamma \hat{x}_1\hat{p}_2\right)|p\rangle_1|x\rangle_2
& =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\!\!\int\!\mathrm dp'
e^{-ixp'}
|p-i\gamma p'\rangle_1
|p'\rangle_2
.
\end{align}
This is almost a position eigenstate $|x\rangle_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \!\!\int\!\mathrm dp' e^{-ixp'}|p'\rangle_2$, except, of course, that you have that ugly correlated momentum structure $|p-i\gamma p'\rangle_1 |p'\rangle_2$ over $p'\in\mathbb R$, and there isn't that much that you can do about it in that form.

This does, however, point at the fact that there are funky correlations going on in there, so that's one interesting place to look. In particular, you can probably find linear combinations of $\hat{x}_1$, $\hat{x}_2$, $\hat{p}_1$ and $\hat{p}_2$ such that $\exp\left(\gamma \hat{x}_1\hat{p}_2\right)|p\rangle_1|x\rangle_2$ is an eigenstate of them - and I'll leave them to you to work out as I've run out of time.